# Transpose comma seperated data into rows - some clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

Let say I have a data

```
ID   String
-------------------
1       John, Adam
```

Based on the below query transpose comma seperated data into rows

```
 SELECT A.[ID],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [ID],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([string], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

**Now, I would like to know what is the reason to have `'.'` and `<M>` in our query?**

**PN: Instead of flagging the post please let me know I will delete the post if it should not be post.**

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the string within the CAST, you will see that your text string has been turned into an XML string.  The '.' in the split command is merely a location in which to start parsing the XML.

Comment: Didn't get it if I select this part only `SELECT [ID],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([string], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA` I will get string like this `<M>John</M><M>Adams</M>`

Answer (score 0):

If it is sql server 2016 you can use string_split

```
create table commasep
( 
id int identity(1,1)
,string nvarchar(100)
)

insert into commasep (string) values ('John, Adam'), ('test1,test2,test3')

select id, [value] as String from commasep 
 cross apply string_split(string,',')
```